# how to suppress loading related nested entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities in my spring boot app, which is serving an API for a front end:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_company")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_company", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String shortName;
}

@Entity
public class Plant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_plant")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_plant", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String location;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="companyid", nullable = false)
    private Company company;
}

@Entity
public class PlantArea {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_plantarea")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_plantarea", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="plantid", nullable = false)
    private Plant plant;
}
```

Each `company` can have one or more `plants` and each `plant` can have one or more `plantareas`. Notice, that I don't have any `List` properties in the entities, this is not needed.

For querying the entities I use `@EntityGraph` in order to avoid the famous n+1 select problem.

This is how I get all plants in the repository interface:

```
@EntityGraph(type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH, attributePaths = {"company"})
List<Plant> findAll();
```

Since the API needs the related `company` entity, I fetch it. With this I get what I want, it's all fine.

Now, this is how I get all plant areas:

```
@EntityGraph(type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH, attributePaths = {"plant", "plant.company"})
List<PlantArea> findAll();
```

Notice the `plant.company` attribute path. With this I get obviously the full chain of entities: `plantarea` -> `plant` -> `company`. This works too.

But for the front end if I query for all plant areas, I don't need the related `company` entities, just the `plant` entities. But if I remove the `plant.company` attribute path, I get the following error pointing to the `company` property in the `plant` entity:

```
No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

I googled this and can resolve this, if I put this line of code (annotate the `company` property) in the `plant` entity:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

But in this case I get the n+1 select problem and on top I get the related `company` entities too (which I don't want).

So, the question is: how can I select all `plantarea` entities with the related `plant` entity, but without the related `company` entity? And all that without using the above `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation.

Comment: You’re looking to do partial JSON serialisation - you need a view. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: if you consider to take my advice (2) that i already told you in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70731411/339637) , you do not need do worry about such issue. I also just told another user the same advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70761431/339637)

Comment: You are certainly right and I will give it a try today evening.

Answer (score 0):

After studying the DTO pattern, I created this dto:

```
public class PlantAreaDto {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("plant")
    private Plant plant;
    @JsonProperty("company")
    private Company company;
}
```

Note, that the `company` property is no more part of the entity, I removed it and populate it in the mapper like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PlantAreaMapper extends BaseMapper<PlantAreaDto, PlantArea> {
    @Override
    @Mapping(target = "company", source = "plant.company")
    PlantAreaDto toDto(PlantArea plantArea);
}
```

And the repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface PlantAreaRepository extends JpaRepository<PlantArea, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH, attributePaths = {"plant", "plant.company"})
    List<PlantArea> findAll();
}
```

With this I got, what I wanted:

- no need to persist the `company` entity in the db, instead it will be populated from the `plant` property
- the `company` property of the `plant` entity is now fetched from db, but I don't have the n+1 select problem and I don't get the `No serializer found...` error
- I get all the data with one query